# Salesforce List of Sobject with group by

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to get a unique list from contacts using group by but for some reason I am getting an error. If I use Workbench with the same SOQL query it would fines but I am getting a Syntax Error in Apex.

```
List<Contact> lstContact = ([SELECT ID, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN: pAddress group by ID, Name, Email]);
```

> Error: Illegal assignment from `List<AggregateResult>` to `List<Contact>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return type of any query using grouping and aggregate functions is [`List<AggregateResult>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

You can iterate over the `AggregateResult` objects (after changing the type of your variable `lstContact`) to get the data you're querying, or you can approach the issue in a different way. It's not clear from your included code why you need to group at all, since you're not using any aggregate functions. You can query with an `IN` clause and even do `ORDER BY Email` if you'd like to sort your Contacts in that way.

If what you want is a count of Contacts with a given email address, with one unique row per email, you could do

```
List<AggregateResult> lstContact = [SELECT count(Id) recordCount, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :pAddress GROUP BY Email];

for (AggregateResult ar : listContact) {
    System.debug('Count of email ' + ar.get('Email') + ' is ' + ar.get('recordCount'));
}
```

Comment: Yep just seen that. Do you happen to know how to loop through the list like you would the Sobject?

Comment: I've added an example of how to access `AggregateResult` properties.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with `AggregateResult` is that using the `get()` method returns an `Object`. In most cases, you'll need to explicitly type-cast the result to be able to use it (e.g. `myContact.email = (String)ar.get('email');`)

Comment: minor nit - alias `count` is not supported; reserved word. Needs to be something like 'countByEmail`

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the catch. Fixed.